# Laravel How to save path of img on db

Tags: laravel

Question: how i can store the path on table posts-> path

$path = public_path('image').$imageName; doesn't work

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate(request(),[

        'title' => 'required',

        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',

        'body' => 'required',

    ]);

    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('image'), $imageName);


    auth()->user()->publish(

        new Post(request(['title','body', 'path']))
    );


    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');


    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would approach it:

Your validation request was wrong also its not `request()` see below:

```
 public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        'body' => 'required',

    ]);

    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        $path = public_path('path/to/image/folder');

        $name= $files->getClientOriginalName();

        $files->move($path, $name);
    }

    $userid = Auth::user()->id;

    $post->create([
        'user_id' => $userid,
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'body' => $request->get('body'),
        'path' => $name (for image)
    ]);

    session()->flash('message', 'your post has now been published');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

If you'd rather store the path, change $name to $path and it'll save the path for you.

**Note:** the `$request->get()` may need to be changed to suit your `name=" "` fields from the form.

Comment: Assuming your query will be fetching the ID of the image you simply run a query to get it.

Comment: ah ok! i ll try

Comment: I've added both options there, $name being the name of the image or $path being the path.. Whichever suits..

Comment: i have update my code, but now the posts haven't the specific user_id

Comment: How are you assigning the post to a specific user, is there a field in the posts table of userid?

Comment: There's foreign key user_id in posts table

Comment: before i add it in my Post model ( new Post)

Comment: @Matteo, please see the update. I have added the usersId into the posts create query. This will assign the user to the post upon submit.

Comment: ok now it works,i have the path of my image(storage) . question how i can know which image is for post 1, 2... ?

Comment: This is why I'd personally save `$name` (bring the image name) instead of it's path.

Comment: @Matteo, Only suggestion I could offer is to add perhaps an image field into the database and log it also.

Comment: @Matteo, because basically there's no saved log of what the image is, it won't end up pulling the image across.. This needs to be logged into the DB ideally

Comment: so is not possible save path+nameimage+jpeg in the same field?

Comment: I wouldn't no.. To be honest I don't really get why you want to store the path anyway...

Comment: if i try to store 'name'->$name; it doesnt store nothing

Comment: You don't do `name->$name` you simply just use `$name`

Comment: $post->create([
            'user_id' => $userid,
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'body' => $request->get('body'),
            'name' => $name,
        ]);

Comment: Did you add 'name' to the database and the model fillable?

Comment: haha frequently run into that myself! Good practice to review your code etc ;)

Comment: You'll get there. Good luck!

Comment: last question for display the image on my blade file? {{$post->image}} display only the name

Comment: last question for display the image on my blade file? <img src="/image/{{ $post->image }}"> doesn't work

Comment: @Matteo, You need to `<img src="path/to/images/folder/{{ $post->image }}">`

Comment: @Matteo, I'd suggest opening a second question as this will be to do with the get side of the controller. Make a new question and I'll read through for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this i think it's simpler

```
 try {
        $url = 'http://localhost:8000/storage/' . $request->file('picfile')->store('uploads/UserImage', 'public');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([$e->getMessage()], 501);
    }
```

Where "uploads/UserImage" is the folder where it's going tp be stored

And $url i simply the URL

Comment: It doesn't answer the op's question though. the op wants to know how to save it to the database. I merely pointed out some mistakes the op made.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure u form have enctype="multipart/form-data".
2. php artisan storage:link (this command create a symbolic link
   "public/storage" to "storage/app/public" more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)).
3. Make sure u migration have column to link image. `$table->string('image')->nullable();`
4. Check u model post and add image to $fillable (mass assignment,
   more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment))
5. Blade: Acces to img url `{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}`

I wish I had helped you.